# Write and read mix data in file

Tags: java, java-io

I want to write and read data on and from files, which start with a word (string) then an array of byte, in file.My file is so huge and its content is like:

```
book byte[] array1 
bench byte[] array2
......

......
```

**I am looking for an efficient way to do this task, Is my way of implementation is efficient?**, since I am not familiar with Java-IO I need your help.

The following code is what I have implemented to write a line in a file so far,

```
FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(fileName,true);
BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
bufferWritter.write(key+" ");
byte[] compressPostings=compress.compress(postings);


FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
fos.write(compressPostings);
fos.close();

bufferWritter.newLine();
bufferWritter.close();
fileWritter.close();
```

**My second question is how can I read from this file?**

Comment: how about `String.getBytes ()`

Comment: @ Scary Wombat I asked about reading a file since The type of the data that is written in each line is not only byte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach suffers from two major problems as it is basically a mix of a textual and a binary file.

1. if your arrays don't have a constant length, you don't know where the array ends and
2. if you use a delimiter character, such as \n, this can naturally occur in the byte array.

Now of course, you can encode the byte array, for instance in base64 but this strikes me as really unelegant.
Unfortunately, you do not make it clear exactly how the format is specified right now and whether you may modify it.

If you may, I would circumvent all those problems and let Java Serialization handle it with a few transformations of your data as list of arrays, where the even indices contain the names and the odd ones the binary data. The toString method is just to show that it works, and you may want to add a convenience function getRow() as well.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInput;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutput;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class HybridFile implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<byte[]> data = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addRow(String s,byte[] a)
    {
        data.add(s.getBytes()); // add encoding if necessary
        data.add(a);
    }

    @Override public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        synchronized (data)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<data.size();i+=2)
            {
                sb.append(new String(data.get(i)));
                sb.append(Arrays.toString(data.get(i+1))+"\n");
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        HybridFile hf = new HybridFile();
        hf.addRow("peter",new byte[] {1,2,3});
        hf.addRow("jaqueline",new byte[] {4,5,6});

        try(ObjectOutput output = 
                new ObjectOutputStream(
                        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("hybrid"))))
        {output.writeObject(hf);}

        ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("hybrid")));
        HybridFile hf2 = (HybridFile)input.readObject();

        System.out.println(hf2);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
peter[1, 2, 3]
jaqueline[4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create [FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) instance for your file.

In this class there is declared the following method:

```
public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException
```

Use it and process read bytes as you want. If there should be a string, convert these bytes to string.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this example :-

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.DoubleBuffer;
import java.nio.LongBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long[] primes = new long[] { 1, 2, 3, 5, 7 };
    File aFile = new File("C:/test/primes.txt");
    FileOutputStream outputFile = null;
    try {
      outputFile = new FileOutputStream(aFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
    FileChannel file = outputFile.getChannel();
    final int BUFFERSIZE = 100;
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(BUFFERSIZE);
    DoubleBuffer doubleBuf = buf.asDoubleBuffer();
    buf.position(8);
    CharBuffer charBuf = buf.asCharBuffer();
    for (long prime : primes) {
      String primeStr = "prime = " + prime;
      doubleBuf.put(0, (double) primeStr.length());
      charBuf.put(primeStr);
      buf.position(2 * charBuf.position() + 8);
      LongBuffer longBuf = buf.asLongBuffer();
      longBuf.put(prime);
      buf.position(buf.position() + 8);
      buf.flip();
      try {
        file.write(buf);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
      }
      buf.clear();
      doubleBuf.clear();
      charBuf.clear();
    }
    try {
      System.out.println("File written is " + file.size() + "bytes.");
      outputFile.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are going to add newline per each byte array, use readLine() methods in any XXXXReader class in Java would be convenient. It will read line by line, so you don't need to use read() or read(byte[] b). Of course read() or read(byte[] b) works, but you might need to add some additional logic to process bytes that you read from file.

Comment: Is there any way to divide different entity without using newline? Is it a right way to write and read?

Comment: You can either define your own protocol to store those metadata or just make very simple format that enforce specific format something like

[four byte to specify how many payload will be following][actual payload][another four byte to specify how many payload will be following][actual payload]

etc.. so you can get payload size by reading first four bytes.